# Using Two Pandas Dataframes: Create a column in DF1 that is a count of how many times a combination of values occurs in df2 with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames, df2 is a subset of df1. The data represents call center phone calls. df1 is all calls for the time frame, df2 represents calls that abandoned before being picked up.

I want to create multiple new columns in df2 that are counts of how many times the phone number in the row called back after abandoning.

df1:

| contact_id | ANI_DIALNUM | DATE | TIME | DateTime | ABANDONED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1323 | 1231231234 | 01/01/2021 | 13:30 | 01/01/2021 13:30 | Y |
| 1324 | 1231231235 | 01/01/2021 | 16:30 | 01/01/2021 16:30 | N |
| 1325 | 1231231234 | 01/01/2021 | 17:30 | 01/01/2021 13:30 | N |

df2:

| contact_id | ANI_DIALNUM | DATE | TIME | DateTime | ABANDONED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1323 | 1231231234 | 01/01/2021 | 13:30 | 01/01/2021 13:30 | Y |

- New column 1: "PotentialSameDayCallBacks"
- New column 2: "NextDayCallBacks
- New Column 3: "Next7DayCallBacks"

DF1 is ~750,000 rows
DF2 is ~175,000 rows

With the small example tables above I would expect df2:

| contact_id | ANI_DIALNUM | DATE | TIME | DateTime | ABANDONED | PotentialSameDayCallBacks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1323 | 1231231234 | 01/01/2021 | 13:30 | 01/01/2021 13:30 | Y | 1 |

I have attempted looping and using a .apply(lambda ....) but both are extremely extremely slow.

```py
abandons['PotentialSameDayCallBacks'] = abandons.apply( lambda x: len(df[(df['Date'] == x['Date'])  & (df['ANI_DIALNUM'] == x['ANI_DIALNUM']) & (df['DateTime'] > x['DateTime'])]), axis=1 )
```

```py
for index, row, in abandons.iterrows():
    abanCounts.append( df[(df['Date'] == row['Date']) & (df['ANI_DIALNUM'] == row['ANI_DIALNUM']) & (df['DateTime'] > row['DateTime'])]['contact_id'].count() )

abandons['PotentialSameDayCallBacks'] = abanCounts
```

I also tried vectorization but the series / df are different lengths so I keep hitting a roadblock there I don't know how to get around.

```py
def countPotentialCallBacks(ani,startDate,startTime):
    
    return df.loc[ (df['ANI_DIALNUM'] == ani) & (df['Date'] == startDate) & (df['DateTime'] > startTime) ]['contact_id'].count()

countPotentialCallBacks(abandons['ANI_DIALNUM'].values, abandons['Date'].values, abandons['DateTime'].values)
```

What would the best approach be to doing this? I believe I have two working solutions, they are just extremely slow. I am very new to this whole thing so I am sure there is a much better way to approach it, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working, still validating.

- giant list of phone calls into a contact center
- When a call abandons, what percentage of the volume for the day is a result of a callback (if a call abandons, how often do we see that ani again the same day)
- If we staff up to prevent x abandons, what's the true impact due to the callbacks caused by abandons?
- Same question but looking at the next day and the next 7 days

I could do this fairly quickly with sql and keep talking myself out of doing just that using sqlite in memory. Trying to learn Pandas with this.

```py
df = df.assign( PotentialSameDayCallBacks = df.sort_values('DateTime').groupby(['ANI_DIALNUM','Date']).cumcount())

df = df[df.abandon == 'Y']

df = df.groupby(['ANI_DIALNUM','Date'])['PotentialSameDayCallBacks'].max().sort_values(ascending=False).to_frame()

noSameDayCallBacks = df[df['PotentialSameDayCallBacks'] == 0]['PotentialSameDayCallBacks'].count()
sameDayCallBacks = df[df['PotentialSameDayCallBacks'] > 0]['PotentialSameDayCallBacks'].count()

sameDayCallBacks / df4['PotentialSameDayCallBacks'].count()
```